# JMeter FTP tests failing on Linux FTP for 1000 users

Tags: linux, ftp, jmeter

We are firing JMeter FTP tests (1000 users) from Windows VM on FTP server (RHEL 6.2). (FTP is 1CPU, 60GB HDD, 4GB RAM) 
And we are getting below errors after some time:
**Response message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 128kfile (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open).**

And there are 12% errors seen in the report after test gets over. 
Here is the test plan used:
*Thread group has 1000 threads. ramp up period is 600 seconds. Total Duration is 780 seconds.
FTP request has server IP, port number as 21, remote file and local file given. 
request is get(RETR). 
Username and pwd is given.*

Below are the contents of vsftpd.conf file of RHEL FTP

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
max_per_ip=5000
#Max no. of allowed connections per IP Address.
max_clients=5000
#Max no. of different IP Addressed which are allowed to connect.
anon_max_rate=3600
use_localtime=YES
idle_session_timeout=1800
data_connection_timeout=1800
```

And test never stops on it's own, we have to forcefully close application.
We tried running this from command prompt and facing the same issue.

```
jmeter -n -t FTPTest.jmx -l FTPTest_itr1.jtl
```

Please suggest the way to remove errors so that tests will have 100% pass rate.

Comment: more info? Is it file read or file write causing the exception? Do you read and write to the same files repeatedly? Do you have anti-virus scanning the files you downloaded?

Comment: thanks CharlieS. It is the file read request as mentioned above (get(RETR)), which results in problem :(  And, yes the 128k file is scanned by antivirus, it is clean. I feel there is some issue related to FTP settings which is causing problem, but unable to pin point.

Comment: i think your file is being accessed by another program while you are trying to access it. does it still occur when you switch the anti-virus program off? are there any other processes that may be trying to access the same file?

Comment: thanks CharlieS. Anti virus on Jmeter machine we cannot stop unfortunately, but with same Jmeter machine when I fire test on Windows FTP, it runs successfully. Regarding any other process trying to access the same file, no other app or process is configured in such a way. Any tool you / anyone suggests to monitor the file access by other process?

Comment: Linux use lsof, Windows use process explorer, cygwin, or some sysinternals tools

Comment: thanks Charlie. We studied it. We have disabled the Antivirus services on Jmeter machine and now the test is running successfully. Thanks for all help.